# Oracle hints - need to find execution plan

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

*Oracle hints* i have came across all the site, which is related to it. but, i didn't understood that concepts. 
my question is 
1. is it helpful to optimize query performance ?
2. is it only of hint regarding complex query or logic?
or any other ?

```
EG: select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(10) */ * from track ;
                         &
    select * from track ;
```

performance wise both took 0.109 sec ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you don't know whether to use hints or not - then don't. Oracle database's optimizer is smart enough to choose an optimal execution plan for your query.

If you are using CBO (cost-based optimizer) (and yes, you should), you have to analyze tables (i.e. gather statistics, and do it regularly) so that the optimizer would deal with relevant data; there's no use if optimizer thinks there are 1000 rows in a table, while you now have 100.000.000 rows - plan would most probably change *a lot*.

A hint instructs the optimizer that it should execute a query the way you said (by providing the hint). Well, that hint might be wrong and the final result will be a worse solution than it was without a hint.

So - don't use them.

Comment: Why? They are not bad, but should be used as necessary...vs by default.

Comment: I'd say that you understood it *wrong*. You should NOT use hints, especially not if you don't know what they are and what they do.